# action not triggered on click of enter in text field-ember

Tags: ember.js, action, ember-cli

I have used the following input

```
{{input type="text" class="form-control tweetSearch"
  id="twitterSearch" value=twitterSearch placeholder="Find Tweets" enter="searchTwitter"}}
```

but the action in the controller is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks good to me. if you got the controller like the below

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      actions: {    
        searchTwitter(){
          console.log("searchTwitter");
        }
      }
    });
```

Just ensure your code is in corresponding hbs. if you can show your controller and hbs file, we can figure it out easily.